# Is it possible to force the order of items in the inline lookup dialog other than alphanumerically by name?

Tags: forms, sorting, dynamics-crm-2015

I have a Lookup type field on a Contact Form in our Dynamics CRM 2015 system which I would like to override the sort order for.

I have tried adding a numeric "SortBy" field to the relevant Entity which is the subject of the lookup and then edited its Lookup View, but the list I see on the Form when I open the inline lookup dialog is not sorted as I have requested.

If I go ahead and click the "Look Up More Records" link from the bottom of the 10 items listed in the inline lookup dialog, the full "Look Up Record" dialog opens and my specified sort order is employed.

I have also tried creating an entirely new View (with my desired sort settings) to target the field at, but this also didn't respect the sort I specified when viewed through the inline lookup dialog.

Is there any way for me to get this same sort to be used in the inline lookup dialog itself? I found a couple of Microsoft threads [here](https://community.dynamics.com/crm/f/117/t/156781) and [here](https://community.dynamics.com/crm/f/117/t/144054) which suggest it is not possible in Dynamics 2015 - if so, can anyone confirm whether it is possible in Dynamics CRM 2016/365?

Comment: AFAIK there is no way to enforce your own sorting in the inline dropdown (I know, that's sad)

Comment: What's a shame is that it's totally possible for an Option Set, just not for a Lookup. Sad indeed if true. 